# How to update on mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have collection, structure like below,
How can I update **`tags` field**  with:

`_id: 556c1c836e80082821f41d9f`

`_versions.id: 556c1c836e80082821f41da6`

`_versions._data._id: 556c71735ddb5010067f1beb`

```
[{
     "_id": ObjectId("556c1c836e80082821f41d9f");
     "_name": "Product 1"
     "_curr_version": ObjectId("556c1c836e80082821f41da6")
     "_versions": [{
         "_id": ObjectId("556c71735ddb5010067f1be6"),
         "_data": [{
                 "_id": ObjectId("556c1cae82b9a3101787d20f"),
                 "_tags": ['sport', 'football']
             }, {
                 "_id": ObjectId("556c71735ddb5010067f1beb"),
                 "tags": ['golf']
             }

         ]
     },

     {
         "_id": ObjectId("556c1c836e80082821f41da6"),
         "_data": [{
                 "_id": ObjectId("556c1cae82b9a3101787d20f"),
                 "_tags": ['sport', 'swimming']
             }, {
                 "_id": ObjectId("556c71735ddb5010067f1beb"),
                 "tags": ['tenis']
             }

         ]
     }

     ]

 }]
```

Comment: for this kind of multi level update use programming language code, still mongoDB not provide this kind of query check [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14164)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongoose MongoDB: updating objects in a nested array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260573/mongoose-mongodb-updating-objects-in-a-nested-array)

Comment: I work on nodejs and use mongosee driver to access to mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

I work on nodejs and use mongosee driver to access to mongodb. I have find a solution.

- Before i get `_versions._data._id: 556c71735ddb5010067f1beb` position store as `pos` var
- after that i have:

  ```
  var ObjectId = require('mongoskin').ObjectID;
  var setObject = {};
  setObject["_versions.$._data."+ pos +"._tag"] = ['a','b'];
  db.use("MongoDB").collection('collections').update({
          "_id": new ObjectId('556c1c836e80082821f41d9f'),
          "_versions._id": new ObjectId('556c1c836e80082821f41da6')
      },
      {
          $set : setObject
      },
      {},
      cb);
  ```